# Cable size for 10 amp circuit

Tags: electrical, multiway-switch, circuit

I’m UK based & I’m building a workshop where I want to be able to switch the dust extraction on or off from multiple locations. My intention is to use 2 2-way switches and 2 intermediate switches, all rated at 10 amps with a standard UK 13 amp socket for the dust extractor to plug into. I will clearly label the socket “10 amp max”. I have a 10amp type C MCB for the consumer unit. The question is am I ok to use 1.5mm T&E or do I need to use 2.5mm?  1.5 will be ok for the current but am I ok to connect a power socket using the 1.5?

Comment: I think your question is "Are 13A sockets allowed on 10A circuits".

Comment: Thanks, yes, that was a better way of thinking about it.  I've decided to use 2.5mm cable.